# Returning error message using SweetAlert

Tags: c#, viewbag, sweetalert, asp.net-boilerplate

In `AccountController`, I notice that the sample registration code catches `UserFriendlyException` and returns the error message in the `ViewBag`.

How can I return it from a SweetAlert?

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // Code omitted for brevity
    }
    catch (UserFriendlyException ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message; // I need to return this using SweetAlert

        return View("Register", model);
    }
}
```

html code

```
  <form action="javascript:;" id="register-form" class="login-form" method="post">
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            <span>Enter required fields. </span>
        </div>

        @if (@ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
            </div>
           <script>abp.message.error("@ViewBag.ErrorMessage");</script>
            <input type="hidden" value=" @ViewBag.ErrorMessage" id="hf_error" >
        }



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group" autocomplete="off" name="name" placeholder="@L("Name")" required autofocus id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@L("Surname")" name="surname" required id="surname"  />
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group" autocomplete="off" name="password" placeholder="@L("Password")" required autofocus id="password">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                <div class="forgot-password" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Login")" id="register-btnd" class="forget-password">Login To Your Account</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                <button class="btn green" id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </form>
```

jquery function below

```
 var jsonObject = {
            Name: name,
            Surname: surname,
            //EmailAddress: email,
           // UserName: username,
            Password: password
        };


        abp.ajax({
            url: abp.appPath + 'Account/Register',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
        }).done(function(data) {

            alert("done");


        }).fail(function(data) {

           alert("fail");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since that method returns a `View` result, it makes sense to use `ViewBag` for the error message.

To show a SweetAlert, add the following in `@section Scripts` in [Register.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b5c18c989fa236d768d3ec6662edb5d66b4612c3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Account/Register.cshtml#L16-L24):

```cs
@section Scripts {
    // ...

    @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        <script>abp.message.error("@ViewBag.ErrorMessage");</script>
      /*<script>swal("@ViewBag.ErrorMessage", "", "error");</script>*/
    }
}
```

Both `<script>` tags trigger identical popups.

Comment: I know that example is without a script, but i want  to create that page same way as the login page